# Kill Oracle sessions using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle, session, kill

How do you get a vb.net program to send a session kill command to Oracle?  I can do it in sqlplusw by just typing:

alter system kill session '45,30665';

In vb.net, I'm trying to do this with an oracle.dataAccess object:

```
oraConn As New OracleConnection("Data Source=db1;User ID=usr;Password=pw")
oraConn.Open()

Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
cmd.Connection = oraConn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "alter system kill session '45,30665';"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
```

When it gets to the ExecuteNonQuery line, it throws an exception "ORA-00911: invalid character".  I think it's expecting an SQL statement.  I'm using VB Express 2008.

Comment: The ORA-00911 error is being thrown because you don't want a semicolon in your statement.  There may be other errors as well.

Comment: I'll be durned.  I can't believe it was that simple.  Removed the semicolon and it works now.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want semicolons in statements that you're sending from a client.  Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the `alter system`

```
cmd.CommandText = "alter system kill session '45,30665'"
```